# Purpose of bookmark, imgcache and rev_geocoding files in cache?

Tags: files, cache

I have an Alcatel and on my Android internal storage in my cache has all of these files with question marks and I can't view them and these files are:

```
bookmark.0
bookmark.1
Bookmark.idx
img.cache.1
imgcache.idx
rev_geocoding.0
rev_geocoding(0).1
rev_geocoding(1).1
rev_geocoding(2).1
rev_geocoding(3).1
rev_geocoding(4).1
rev_geocoding(5).1
rev_geocoding(6).1
```

and they're all saying "file format not supported".  What does this mean what do these files mean and how can I view these files?

Comment: Your title contains the answer: "Cache". I've added the related tag (`cache`), and you might wish to take a look at the corresponding tag-wiki ([cache](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/cache/info)). Though it's pretty short, it's a valid answer to your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Those are cache files for specific apps and *can usually only be read by the specific apps which they belong to*.

If you *really* want to try to look at them (although they will probably not be readable by a human), you can install an app like [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) and open the file as a text file.